# Not been able to navigate to login screen , after logout.

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

> I am using ReactNavigation and after SignIn , i enter my home page. My home page has 4 tabs, and on 4th tab i have logout button. After clicking on logout button , i should get back to SIGN IN screen.

**The issue i am facing is , i am not been able to reset the TAB NAVIGATOR.**

```
          this.props.navigation.dispatch({
        type: NavigationActions.NAVIGATE,
        routeName: 'SignIn',
        action: {
          type: NavigationActions.RESET,
          index: 0,
          actions: [{type: NavigationActions.NAVIGATE, routeName: 'SignIn'}]
        }
      })
```

I tried applying above chunk of code to navigate , but it did not work. Please tell me , how to get out of tab navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Your root-level navigation should be a `StackNavigator` with children looking something like this:

- Welcome screen
- Login screen
- Tab Navigator (for logged in home screen)

  - Tab 1
  - Tab 2
  - Tab 3
  - Tab 4 (with logout button)

To reset the `TabNavigator`, you shouldn't dispatch an action of type `NavigationActions.NAVIGATE` because that will push onto the current navigation stack, instead of removing the tab navigator from the state. Instead, consider using a [Reset action](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset). So the code within your logout function should have:

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login'})
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Comment: That's the exact thing i am using , but , TabNavigator is just not getting reset.
My scenario here is , each tab is with in a tab navigator and each each has it's own stack navigator. 
TAB: 4 isn't navigating to  sign In screen (becuase it's not in stack navigator of 4th tab), If i include it in 4th tab's stack navigator , then other 3 tabs are not reset.

Comment: What happens when you try to dispatch the reset action instead of navigate action?

Comment: @PatNeedham Is there any other way to reset cache or app over logout

Comment: @Sau_Patil what are you storing in cache which needs to be reset?

Comment: @PatNeedham i want to reset whole app cache to login with other account
As mentioned in above code i am getting following error
There is no route defined for keyTabView

Comment: @Sau_Patil please refer me to the above code (as well as your logout function), I'm not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

onPress of Logout we are calling below code

```
  const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "SignIn" })],
    key: null 
  });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

This is our AppNavigation file is there any way to reset app on Logout

```
const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator(
  {
    SignIn: {
      screen: SignIn,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen: SignUp,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    },
    TabsScreen: {
      screen: TabsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "float",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#ffffff" },
        gesturesEnabled: true,
        header: null,
      }
    },
)
export const sideMenuStack = StackNavigator({
    SideMenu: {
        screen: SideMenu,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerMode: "none",
            header: null
        }
    },
    Settings: {
        screen: Settings,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: "Settings",
        })
    },
    SignIn: {
      screen: SignIn,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    },
)
export const FeedsStack = StackNavigator({
    FeedsStack: {
        screen: FeedsStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerMode: "none",
            header: null
        }
    },
    Post: {
        screen: Post,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: "Post",
        })
    },
)
export const UserStack = StackNavigator({
    UserStack: {
        screen: UserStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerMode: "none",
            header: null
        }
    },
    Friends: {
        screen: Friends,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: "Friends",
        })
    },
)
export const TabView = TabNavigator(
  {
    FeedsStack: {
      screen: FeedsStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Feeds",
        scrollEnabled: true,
        focussed: true,
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
          <Image
            source={Images.feedsActive}
            style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
          />
      }
    },
    UserStack: {
      screen: UserStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Users",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
          <Image
            source={Images.UserActive}
            style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
          />
      }
    },
    sideMenuStack: {
      screen: sideMenuStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "More",
        headerMode: "screen",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
          <Image
            source={Images.moreActive}
            style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
          />
      }
    }
  },
  //Default configurations for Tabs
  {
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
       indicatorStyle:{
        borderBottomColor:'#32a1fe',
        borderBottomWidth:3
      },
      showLabel: true,
      backBehavior: "none",
      showIcon: true,
      activeTintColor:"#338AD8",
      inactiveTintColor:"#BEC5CB",
      upperCaseLabel:false,
      labelStyle :[styles.labelStyle],
    }
  }
);
```